# How to get Mysql rownum continously over the pagenation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically, i want to display the number of rows from table along with the data by using @rownum it works just fine for first page but when we go to the next page we it start with row one again.

query code:

```
$sql = "SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum, t.*FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, (select * from tbl) t 
         LIMIT $Page_Start , $Per_Page";
```

pagenation code:

```
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass") or die("Error Connect to Database");
`enter code here`$objDB = mysql_select_db("WEB");
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM line ";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
$Num_Rows = mysql_num_rows($objQuery);

$Per_Page = 2; // Per Page

$Page = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["Page"]);
if(!$_GET["Page"])
{
 $Page=1;
 }

 $Prev_Page = $Page-1;
 $Next_Page = $Page+1;

 $Page_Start = (($Per_Page*$Page)-$Per_Page);
  if($Num_Rows<=$Per_Page)
 {
 $Num_Pages =1;
 }
 else if(($Num_Rows % $Per_Page)==0)
 {
 $Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page) ;
 }
 else
 {
  $Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page)+1;
  $Num_Pages = (int)$Num_Pages;
   }
```

pagenation usage:

```
if($Prev_Page)
{
echo "<a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$Prev_Page'> Back</a> &nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp; ";
}

if($Page!=$Num_Pages)
{
echo " <a href ='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$Next_Page'>Next</a> ";
}
```

So i want the number of row continuously increase page after pages
example page 1  row 1-5 and page2 should be 6-10 something like that

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you add a parameter in your SQL query to initialize rownum to pagestart instead of 0?  That way it should increment as the page increases I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the calculation to get row number inside a subquery and limit it on the outer `SELECT` statement so the row_number won't break, ex,

*the column name and table name might be different form your example above but the thought of the query is the same.*

```
SELECT  RowNumber, Student_ID, Student_Name
FROM
        (
            SELECT  @rownum := @rownum + 1 RowNumber,
                    t.*
            FROM    student t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) s
            ORDER   BY t.Student_ID
        ) subQ
// LIMIT    0, 3
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with LIMIT but continues even in pagenation*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8a8a/9)

Comment: Thanks JW It almost work but i have no idea how to put two sql query in the same page because if i put them together the first one wont work

Comment: what do you mean by two sql query? You only need one. you just need to  manipulate `LIMIT`.

Comment: Sorry JW it works like a charm now just ignore comment above i was confusing myself Thank you very much.