# MySQL Simple row num incremental counter

Tags: mysql, sql, random, row-number

I'm trying to produce an incremental counter (column 'rownum' in the query below) in an SQL select clause. the counter should start over each time a new user switches.

```
    SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT('    ',g.node1,'    ',g.node2),
    @r:= CASE WHEN @g = g.`user` THEN @r +1 ELSE 1 END rownum,
    @g:= g.`user` user_group
    FROM sn.sn_graph_reduced g
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @g:=0,@r:=0) t2
    ORDER BY `user` , RAND() 
    ) t
    WHERE rownum <= 100
```

However, the above code snippet returns the row number, and since the records are RANDOMLY sampled, the row numbers are not incremental.
What I need is a simple counter (1,2,3....) for each row returned.
thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880080/how-to-get-mysql-rownum-continously-over-the-pagenation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the variable outside of the inline view:

```
SELECT t.*,
       @r:= CASE WHEN @t = t.`user` THEN @r +1 ELSE 1 END rownum,
       @t:= t.`user` user_group
FROM    (
        SELECT CONCAT('    ',g.node1,'    ',g.node2), g.`user`
        FROM sn.sn_graph_reduced g
        ORDER BY `user` , RAND()
        ) t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @t:=0,@r:=0) t2
where rownum <= 100
```

Comment: the counter comes up well, but the query returns only 100 records for the first user (there are 27 users so i would expect 2700 records)

Comment: @user3628777 try my edit, sorry I thought the purpose of your "where rownum <= 100" was to limit the results to 100 rows, but I think it's actually limiting the results to 100 groups?

Answer (score 0):

the method for incrementing row number doesn't cope with RAND() directly, so use values from rand() as a column. Also initiate @g as '' not zero and then you need a final ORDER BY.

```
SELECT
      *
FROM (
            SELECT
                  CONCAT('    ', g.node1, '    ', g.node2) AS node_concat
                , @r:= IF(@g = g.`user`, @r + 1, 1)        AS rownum
                , @g:= g.`user`                            AS user_group
            FROM (
                   SELECT *, rand() AS R FROM sn_graph_reduced
                   ) g
                  CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @g:= '' ,@r:= 1 ) t2
            ORDER BY
                  `user`
                , R
      ) t
WHERE rownum <= 100
ORDER BY
       user_group
     , rownum
;
```

see: [This SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21a97/1)

Comment: No problem, I found that if combining the row calculation with rand() that it just wasn't working as you'd expect. So it's OK for you? A tick is always nice to get :)